# Портирование класса RSA для RDP с Java на C#

Tags: java, c#, криптография, rsa

Прошу помочь в портировании имплиментации RSA шифрования для протокола RDP с Java на C#.

Реализация на Java: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240810.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Проблема в разности классов BigIntiger.

Вот что выводит в итоге Java (и никак не получается получить подобные значения на C#):

```
Client random:

0xff 0xee 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xff 

Encrypted client random:

0xc0 0x12 0x96 0x66 0xbe 0x28 0x60 0x7b 
0xb0 0xb4 0x03 0xfe 0xda 0x38 0x6a 0xb9 
0x39 0x9d 0x10 0xa2 0x76 0xb8 0x8b 0x4c 
0xe4 0x25 0x9a 0x22 0x9e 0xe0 0x01 0x34 
0xd4 0xc1 0x37 0x38 0xb7 0xef 0x50 0x09 
0x55 0xc5 0xb3 0x35 0x17 0x9e 0xbd 0x9e 
0x45 0x93 0x3c 0xd8 0x5d 0xe6 0x7c 0xa9 
0xc3 0x70 0x2e 0x18 0xf2 0x23 0x71 0x09 

Decrypted client random:

0xff 0xee 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xff 
0x00
```

p.s. пробовал RSACryptoServiceProvider. Значения modulusBytes, exponentBytes и clientRandomBytes - брал из Java класса. Выдало ошибку при импорте RSAParameters.

**update:** [имплементация класса на C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eea7f200-9dd1-4db5-b97b-1ea974242fbe/-rsa-rdp-java-c?forum=desktopprogrammingru)

Comment: А как вы получали байты для modulus и exponent?

Comment: VMAtm, данные взял отсюда (там в самом низу, в методе Main): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240810.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839274/rsa-encryption-by-supplying-modulus-and-exponent Разница в том, что в RSA на C# нужно передавать PublicKey, а не просто число.

Answer (score 2):

Не изобретайте велосипед, воспользуйтесь [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

Comment: Athari, я не стал использовать криптопровайтера потому что согласно документации "RSACryptoServiceProvider поддерживает размер ключа от 384 до 16384 бит с шагом 8 бит". Да и честно сказать пробовал с modulusBytes, exponentBytes и clientRandomBytes (значения этих параметров брал из Java класса). Выдало ошибку RSAParameters.